# Extra Searchfields

Tags: product-attribute, search

im using Magento 1.9.2.3 for a Car-Shop.

We would like to integreate a extra search with two fields that search alle Products for an attribute.

Example:

Empty Searchfield: [    ] - [   ] [Search]

Filled Searchfield: [0B01]-[763]  [Search]

Attribute on a Product: 0B01-763

After the customer hit search he should find all products for that specific number.

Is there a way to integrate a specific search?

Answer (score 1):

I think enabling advanced search allows what you want. Not loose to enabling for which attribute you want enabling searching (from backend).

Comment: I do not understand much from your answer. Please try to update your answer and make your explanation more clearly and in correct English.

Comment: i put the advanced Search on the Frontpage deactivatet every single attribute that ich not need and that i need activated for the adv search. but how can i splitt now the search field ?

Answer (score 0):

As the shop type is a car shop, i think he means (in german language and shortcuts) HSN/TSN lookup for his articles.

As of this, the answer from emastyle is in deed not wrong.

You have to create two new attributes, in this case named `hsn` and `tsn` and enable it for advanced search. You also have to enable it in an attribute set your articles are using.

Now add the HSN and TSN informations at your articles. Now you can use the advanced search `http://yourshopurl.com/catalogsearch/advanced/` and type in the HSN and TSN and find your products.

I've done a quick test in a local development shop and all works fine. If i type in HSN only, i find all products with the HSN. If i type in HSN and TSN i find the specific product.

If needed, i could edit the post and make some pictures.